# Seed Custom Role Inherited from IdentityRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

this time the problem is when I try to build a class to inherit from IdentityRole like this

```
public class Role : IdentityRole, IObjectState
{
    public Role() { }
    public Role(string name) : base(name) { Name = name; }
    public new string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

then I want to Seed my Database with my Roles, but its Discriminator Column I want it with the value 'Role' not 'IdentityRole'

this my seeding code

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator") || !context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "User"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new List<IdentityRole>()
            {
                new IdentityRole { Name = "Administrator"},
                new IdentityRole { Name = "User"},
            };
            role.ForEach(x => manager.Create(x));
        }
```

when I try this seeding code It's Ok, in its Discriminator Column It says 'IdentityRole' but when I try this one, It doesn't save the Role in the table

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "qwe") || !context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "qweqwe"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<Role>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<Role>(store);
            List<Role> role = new List<Role>()
            {
                new Role() { Name = "qwe"},
                new Role() { Name = "qweqwe"},
            };
            role.ForEach(x => manager.Create(x));
        }
```

I don't know why this code can't save the role, as you can see I should save it because the Role Class has inherited from IdentityRole

What should I do to seed my Roles with different Discriminator?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my solution is very simple lol

I changed this

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "qwe") || !context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "qweqwe"))
    {
        var store = new RoleStore<Role>(context);
        var manager = new RoleManager<Role>(store);
        List<Role> role = new List<Role>()
        {
            new Role() { Name = "qwe"},
            new Role() { Name = "qweqwe"},
        };
        role.ForEach(x => manager.Create(x));
    }
```

for this

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator") || !context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "User"))
        {
            var role = new List<Role>()
            {
                new Role { Name = "Administrator"},
                new Role { Name = "User"},
            };
            role.ForEach(x => context.Roles.Add(x));
        }
```

That's it
I realized that you can seed your table using your context, without instance your ApplicationRole or UserManager